# Read two different files from Scala Spark in single code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two sets of files and Schema I want to run that in a single set of code.

This is my code:

```scala
val file_path = "file1" // I want to pass two files (file1, file2)
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(file_path)
val validJsonRdd = rdd.flatMap(_._2.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "").replace(":value", ":\"value\"").replace("}{", "}\n{").split("\n"))
val dataframe = spark
      .read
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .schema(Schema1) // I want to put schema1 for file1 and schema2 for file2
      .json(validJsonRdd)
      .show()
```

So as per the above code, I want to run two different schemas and their correspondent file.

Comment: pass file location(file1 or file2) and schemahint(true or false) in your spark job as command arguments and use it accordingly ... if schemahint true then set Schema1 otherwise Schema2 in your code.

Comment: I am totally new to it can I get a sample snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass applications arguments into spark-submit as below..

General syntax of [spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

```
./bin/spark-submit \
      --class <main-class> \
      --master <master-url> \
      --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
      --conf <key>=<value> \
      ... # other options
      <application-jar> \
      [application-arguments]
```

in place of [application-arguments] you can have **file.txt** **schema1.txt** (OR) **file1.txt** **scehma2.txt**

**file.txt is 1st argument and schema1.txt is 2nd arguement.**

In your application code, you can something like this

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
     val inputFile = args(0);
     val schemaFile = args(1);
     val schemaFileasString = // open FileInoutStream and read whole schema data from **schemaFile** as string 
     val schema = SchemaConverter.convertContent(schemaFileasString)
     //create spark session and provide all the parameter properly
    import spark.implicits._
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(inputFile)
    val validJsonRdd = rdd.flatMap(_._2.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "").replace(":value", ":\"value\"").replace("}{", "}\n{").split("\n"))

     spark.read
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .schema(schema)
      .json(validJsonRdd)
      .show()
   }
```

References :

https://github.com/zalando-incubator/spark-json-schema

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html